# How is it possible to dynamically make a set of labels on a panel and use it across forms and update it - Delphi

Tags: delphi, dynamic

I have been sitting with this problem for a few days trying to figure out how to solve it.

I'm currently creating an application for a school project, its a movie booking system . So I have got a panel which has the receipt. On the panel is a bunch of labels which shows amount of adult,children tickets; amount of medium,large pop corn & drinks .Then I have got 3 forms : a form to select which type of ticket you want, a form which lets you choose snacks, and a form which allows you to select your seats.

So what i want to do is use this panel across all 3 forms and then update the label captions across it, so that if im for example in the snack selection form and i want to go back to the form which selects tickets, panel will stay the same and have the same label captions.

I've done some research and i understand that i need to dynamically create the panel itself with all labels but im not sure how to do this.
Thanks in advance for any help

This is the panel

[image: This is the panel]

Comment: You don't need to create dynamically - just update the caption properties when needed. That should be enough for a school project, but if you want to take it further you should look into using frames.

Comment: Use `TFrame`. It's can be placed in design-time on different forms\controls. Also, TFrame can be created dynamically, which is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into TFrame and get back asap .